How to create a portable structure to emulate 16-bit registers in C?
I am working on a gameboy emulator. The gameboy CPU uses 16-bit registers whose upper and lower bytes can be accessed and operated on individually as well as the entire 16-bits. How do I implement it to work regardless of the difference in endianness across machines?
This is my current implementation
typedef union register16_t
{
    struct
    {
        uint8_t lo, hi;
    } reg;

    uint16_t reg16;
} register16_t;

I realized that this is not portable because of difference in endianness between machines and started looking for solutions only to get more confused after going through various posts regarding whether the C standard supports type punning using unions. Now I am also confused about whether this kind of implementation is good practice or not.

Use conditional compilation for the order of the lo and hi members. Your build system should be able to figure it out and set appropriate macros that you can check for.

As for type-punning through unions, it's allowed in C (IIRC it's explicitly mentioned in the C specifications). It's not allowed in C++.

If this is an emulation, why do you care how your system stores the data? You are emulating what you want. Just use one of uint16_t or uint8_t[2] and write abstraction for it.

Why does the code needs to be portable if it's an emulator? What other systems than various PC flavours will it run on and why?

@Lundin This is a learning project so I just wanted to do learn to do it the portable way. Practically, it will only ever be compiled by me, since there are better emulators already.

Yes, while union is a simplification, as you see, the endianess of the machine differs. You are emulating your data, there is no reason to depend on any machine specific behavior you are running on. Just write your own abstractions. You could do something along:
struct reg16 { uint16_t v; };
uint16_t reg16_get(const struct reg16 *t) { return t->v; }
void reg16_set(struct reg16 *t, uint16_t v) { t->v = v; }
uint8_t reg16_get_hi(const struct reg16 *t) { return t->v >> 8; }
uint8_t reg16_get_lo(const struct reg16 *t) { return t->v; }
void reg16_set_hi(struct reg16 *t, uint8_t v) { t->v = v << 8 | reg16_get_lo(t); }
void reg16_set_lo(struct reg16 *t, uint8_t v) { t->v = reg16_get_hi(t) << 8 | v; }

And use the functions (abstraction) whenever you need the data. You could also change the representation from uint16_t to uint8_t[2] you feel like it better without changing other parts of the code.

you do not need any structs and pointers

Thanks for the reply! I did this but since I had already abstracted out the instructions and there were only few of them using the entire 16 bits, I just did the manipulations directly in those without creating a new struct.

If you don't want to rely on your build system to detect the byte order, you can retrieve it online as mentioned in see Determining Host Endianness chapter
This way, it will be easy to write the get/set function to access the individual bytes in the correct order, e.g.:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union register16_t
{
    struct
    {
        uint8_t bytes[2];
    } reg;

    uint16_t reg16;
}__attribute__((packed)) register16_t;

unsigned int is_little_endian = 0;
void detect_endianness(void)
{
    uint16_t bytes = 1;
    if (*((uint8_t*) &bytes) == 1)
    {
        is_little_endian = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        is_little_endian = 0;
    }
// use this to test the byte order on a different platform
#define def_fake_byte_order 0
#if def_fake_byte_order
    is_little_endian = !is_little_endian;
#endif
}

// returns the index [0,1] of the LSB in the 16-bit word
unsigned int idx_LSB(void)
{
    return (is_little_endian) ? 0 : 1;
}

// returns the index [0,1] of the MSB in the 16-bit word
unsigned int idx_MSB(void)
{
    return !idx_LSB();
}

// returns the LSB in a 16-bit word
uint8_t get_uint16_t_LSB(const uint16_t ui)
{
    register16_t r;
    r.reg16 = ui;
    return r.reg.bytes[idx_LSB()];
}

// returns the MSB in a 16-bit word
uint8_t get_uint16_t_MSB(const uint16_t ui)
{
    register16_t r;
    r.reg16 = ui;
    return r.reg.bytes[idx_MSB()];
}

// sets the LSB in a 16-bit word
void set_uint16_t_LSB(uint16_t *ui, const uint8_t b)
{
    register16_t r;
    r.reg16 = *ui;
    r.reg.bytes[idx_LSB()] = b;
    *ui = r.reg16;
}

// sets the MSB in a 16-bit word
void set_uint16_t_MSB(uint16_t *ui, const uint8_t b)
{
    register16_t r;
    r.reg16 = *ui;
    r.reg.bytes[idx_MSB()] = b;
    *ui = r.reg16;
}

#define def_low_byte_hex 0x34
#define def_high_byte_hex 0x12
#define def_make_16bit_from_byte_hex(A, B) ((A *256U) + B)

int main(const int argc, char * argv[])
{
    detect_endianness();
    printf("Endianness is %s\n", is_little_endian ? "little-endian" : "big-endian");
    register16_t r;
    r.reg16 = def_make_16bit_from_byte_hex(def_high_byte_hex, def_low_byte_hex);

    {
        const uint8_t low_byte = get_uint16_t_LSB(r.reg16);
        printf("Low  byte of 0x%04X is %02X\n", r.reg16, low_byte);
        const uint8_t high_byte = get_uint16_t_MSB(r.reg16);
        printf("High byte of 0x%04X is %02X\n", r.reg16, high_byte);
    }
    return 0;
}

